# complex htacess set up with wildcard subdomains and ssl

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl, https

I have a wildcard SSL certificate installed that lets me serve up pages for any subdomain over SSL.

For example:
https://www.domain.com
https://test.domain.com
https://demo.domain.com

I need to write some .htaccess rules that do the following.

1. Force WWW and SSL if the domain is ever requested alone

   ex. redirect http://domain.com or https://domain.com to https://www.domain.com
2. Force SSL on all requests that don't have it

   ex. http://anything.domain.com redirects to https://anything.domain.com

EDIT: I understand that there is no way to prevent a cert error if someone requests https://domain.com (no subdomain)

Given that caveat, does the code below seem like the best way to handle the other redirects?

```
# WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysampledomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# SSL
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The SSL cert doesn't work on the domain alone, so if someone requests `https://mysampledomain.com`, they get an error before redirection can occur.

Apart from getting a certificate that covers your base domain as well, there is *nothing* you can do about that.

When my browser requests `https://mysampledomain.com`, the first thing it has to do is handle out the connection encryption with your server. But since your server can not provide a valid SSL certificate for the host name, my browser will say, *“thank you, but no thank you – I can’t trust you and therefor I’m not gonna talk to you any more.”*

You will not even *get* to the point where your server could redirect my browser anywhere else – the encryption happens on a layer above HTTP, and since we can not agree on the encryption, your server does not even get to “talk HTTP” to my browser (and that would be necessary so that you could issue an *HTTP* redirect).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was afraid of. I think this would be an edge case anyway.

Comment: I edited the example above, do think that's about the best that can be done to cover every case?